# Carrier infinity 25vna heat pump utility curtailment

Tags: heating, heat-pump, utilities

I have a newly installed infinity greenspeed hp system and the utility is trying to figure out how to control the outdoor unit in heating mode.

It's my understanding that the utility sends a signal to the UTIL input on the outdoor unit which then gets relayed to the infinity stat for instructions on how to respond to the curtailment demand from the utility.

Under advanced service menu, set up, and utility curtailment, there is a option to set up a response in cooling situations... "Disable, turn off, or low stage". There's no option for what to do in heating mode.

My infinity touch stat shows it as possible to curtail in heating mode in the install manual (page 61). But... It isn't there when I go to implement that option.

I've seen elsewhere on boards that the infinity can not curtail in heat mode, but that would mean the install manual is incorrect. Plus, when I first enter the curtailment menu the option is there for a split second and then disappears. It is almost as if some other selection or setting is preventing it from being displayed.

Any ideas? I would really appreciate help as it is preventing me from receiving a large rebate from the utility

Comment: Where are you on this planet? That would be a useful addition to this question

Comment: Sure. I'm in Minnesota

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility, for that matter?  I wonder if they only really need curtailment in the summer....also, is your heat-pump backed up by strip heat, a gas furnace, or something else?

Comment: Thanks. The utility is telling me that they want to be able to control both heating and cooling to provide me with the lower rate. My backup is strips plus separate electric baseboard, neither of which are utility controlled. Really seems like this is a simple software issue on the infinity control.

Comment: Here's the rub -- since you have strips/baseboard, if they aren't tied into the curtailment system -- when your heatpump heat gets curtailed, the strips/baseboard will kick in to maintain the setpoint, causing your power usage to go *up*, not down.  Whoops!

Comment: Right, but the utility will be getting 12¢ kw instead of 5.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the *utility* won't get the results they expect if they curtail your heatpump heat.  It would be rather counterproductive for them if they hit the curtail button on your house, only to have the load go *up* instead of down, no?

Comment: Also, what's the exact model number on your heat pump's outdoor unit, how many kW of strip heat do you have in your system, and how many kW of baseboards does your house have?

Comment: Last but not least, did you have an ACCA Manual J (heating/cooling load calculation) run when this system was installed?

Answer (score 1):

Only your utility knows what their requirements are specifically.  You may be best getting a different person there to look at your situation.  We have had rebates offered here in Connecticut for ductless heat pumps and as I recall homes that had baseboard heat were disqualified.  But that was without utility regulation.  I suspect you have a case if you can control the built-in strip heaters as long as the Infinity heats a major portion of the house.  For example all but a three season room or mud room.  Be patient and ask questions.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer: keep 'em coming!